# How to iterate over several list at the same time?

Tags: python, django, django-views, python-2.7

I have a bit of a riddle here 
what i want to do is have a "for in" which loops on 3 variables from request.POST and request.FILES
what i did is:

```
images = request.FILES.getlist('image')
titles = request.POST.getlist('title')
captions = request.POST.getlist('caption')
for image,title,caption in images,titles,captions:
```

that doesn't seem to work 
any solutions?

Comment: When using zip as @Acorn said, remember that (quoting the docs): The returned list is truncated in length to the length of the shortest argument sequence.

Comment: +1 for the phrase "with for in"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
for image, title, caption in zip(images, titles, captions):
```

..is what you want. ([zip docs](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip))

Comment: im sorry to bother you but if i want to get what is written in the title field what should i write?

Comment: @omar-mowafi Welcome to StackOverflow! If the answer worked for you, you should "accept" it. That gives the answerer a reputation score and provides the motivation for answering questions here. People will be more likely to help you if you have a high "acceptance" rate.